# Summing values in an array less than a certain value

Tags: python

I have a `3x3` array with numbers and zeroes. I need to take the absolute difference between the next point, `ls[i+1]`, and the point before it, `ls[i]`. Here is an example of my list:

```
ls=[(98.6,99,0),(98.2,98.4,97.1),(97.6,0,98.3)]
```

The zeroes are faulty data. I need a loop that will:

1. Take the **absolute** difference between the future number and the current number in each row,
2. Make the differences greater than the max difference zero
   (`max diff=1.9` in this case given that the zeroes are faulty data),
3. Sum together the differences in each row so that I'm left with a list of the sums.

As it stands now, the end result will be:

```
result=[(0.4,99),(0.2,1.3),(97.6,98.3)]
```

Given that the zeroes are not good data, differences greater than `1.9` are not an accurate result.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the zeros before applying your algorithm?

Comment: Would that not cause error with inconsistent spacing within the list?

Comment: Nobody can tell you since your specifications are still unclear. What is inconsistent spacing supposed to mean? Please answer why you can't make `ls` look like `[(98.6, 99), (98.2, 98.4, 97.1), (97.6, 98.3)]` and then do whatever you do. If you need help building that new list I can show you.

Comment: I understand #1. I think I understand #2. And #3 I fail to see how summing rows in a 3x3 grid gets you a 2x1 list of sums. Your example `result` is a 3x2 matrix.

Comment: Ok, the zeroes are bad data. For the first row, subtracting abs(99-98.6) gives me 0.4. Subtracting abs(0-99) gives me 99 because the zero is not wanted data. I just want an if statement that says if the difference is more than 1.9, then make it a zero. By doing that, when I go to sum them at the end, the erroneous differences won't affect my data.

Comment: @cricket_007, you're right. I messed up on the dimensions.

Comment: @timgeb, I don't know python well but when I've worked in MATLAB, usually matrices that don't have the same amount of numbers in each column throws up an error. Ultimately, it's not what I want.

Comment: But you don't have a matrix, you have a list. You could simply issue `new_ls = [tuple(x for x in t if x) for t in ls]`, then do whatever you do.

Comment: Ok... But my main issue is not knowing how to loop through the data to subtract the differences. I need to go through the first row and subtract the second value from the first, then the third from the second; then go to the next row, and subtract its values... etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy with setting differences over a given maximum difference value to 0, perhaps implement that logic in a 2nd step:

```
ls=[(98.6,99,0),(98.2,98.4,97.1),(97.6,0,98.3)]

unfiltered = [tuple(abs(x1 - x2) for x1, x2 in zip(tup, tup[1:]))
                for tup in ls]
max_diff = 1.9
results = [tuple((x if x < max_diff else 0) for x in tup)
                for tup in unfiltered]
```

If you have objects that are not native python lists/tuples but do support indexing, it might be better to do this:

```
ls=[(98.6,99,0),(98.2,98.4,97.1),(97.6,0,98.3)]

unfiltered = [tuple(abs(item[i] - item[i+1]) for i in range(len(item)-1))
                for item in ls]
max_diff = 1.9
results = [tuple((x if x < max_diff else 0) for x in tup)
                for tup in unfiltered]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm super new at python and I want to use your answer because like the succinctness of this code you have.  If my list said it has 3 elements and each of those elements was 3 values (same as showed in ls above but not a tuple), how would I implement this code? I don't have a tuple in my script... I guess I didn't explain that well.

Comment: sure, what does the data actually look like?  Is it a list of lists?  or numpy arrays?

Comment: @Strak - You do have tuples. In Python a tuple is written like `(1,2,3)` with parenthesis, while lists are written with square brackets. So you *do* have a list of tuples.

Comment: @cricket_007 - I know in the example I gave they are tuples, but what I'm actually working with is not tuples. 
In my actual data, it says type is float64 and the listed value says array([[0... etc.]])... So I guess numpy arrays?

Comment: @Strak: I don't like index-fiddling if I can avoid it, but the second example should work memory-efficiently for pretty much any indexable python objects.  The final output is still a list of tuples.

Comment: Hmm. I need to get better at list comprehension... That second version literally does the same thing as my answer in three lines. :D

Comment: @cricket_007: Yeah python list comprehensions (and their brethren generator expressions) definitely are real beauties!

Comment: I guess the only benefit of my answer is that it avoids out-of-bounds errors on the indexing.

Comment: @cricket_007: You're right about Out-of-Bounds Errors for the first example.  For the 2nd example, I think `range(len(item)-1)` returns an empty list so you get an empty tuple of differences for 0 or 1 element objects, which seems like a reasonable result.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the numbers get all messed up when doing the absolute difference, probably something to do with floating point numbers...

```
ls=[(98.6,99,0),(98.2,98.4,97.1),(97.6,0,98.3)]

def abs_diff(lst, max_diff=1.9):
    n = len(lst)
    if n < 2:
        return lst
    res = []
    for i in range(n-1):
        diff = abs(lst[i] - lst[i+1])
        if diff > max_diff:
            res.append(0)
        else:
            res.append(diff)
    return res

result = map(tuple, map(abs_diff, ls)) 
print result
# [(0.40000000000000568, 0), (0.20000000000000284, 1.3000000000000114), (0, 0)]
```

Comment: Nice! I just want the bad values to be zero.

Comment: By "bad", you mean the 99's? Make those 0? What about the `max_diff` value?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Any difference greater than 1.9 needs to be zero.

Comment: @Strak - Gotcha. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

This should do you. I've broken out your awkward subtraction/clearing of bad values, but you can tail recursively move through the list, building the needed values as you go, filtering out `0`s.

```
def awkward_subtract(a, b):
    if (a is None) or (b is None) or (a == 0) or (b == 0):
        return 0
    else:
        return abs(a - b)

def compare_lists(ls):     
    head, *tail = ls
    if not tail:
        return [list(filter(int(0).__ne__, head))]
    else:
        values = [awkward_subtract(head[x], tail[0][x]) for x in range(0, len(head))]
        return [list(filter(int(0).__ne__, values))] + compare_lists(tail)
```

You can test it in the REPL*:

```
>>> ls = [[98.6,99,0],[98.2,98.4,97.1],[97.6,0,98.3]]
>>> compare_lists(ls)
[[0.3999999999999915, 0.5999999999999943], [0.6000000000000085, 1.2000000000000028], [97.6, 98.3]]
```

(*) I think your test is not quite right, btw.

Note that this uses embedded lists for ease, but it is dead simple to fix that:

```
ts = [(98.6,99,0),(98.2,98.4,97.1),(97.6,0,98.3)]
ls = [list(t) for t in ts]
```